# Linux console with different input / output font size

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, fonts, console

Is there a way to have multiple font sizes in a single linux console?

example:

```
x@system:~$ ls -a    // Font Size 14
.  ..  td            // Font Size 10
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible at all. The terminal (console) is a rectangular grid of characters.

Also, the "input" vs. "output" separation doesn't go as you think it goes. When you press the letter `l` (the first one of the command you type) then it goes through the kernel to your shell, which happens to decide to print an `l` (but it could just as well print anything else), and asks the terminal to print an `l`. In the terminal's eyes these two events are not connected. The received `l` (and subsequently an entire `ls -a` string in your example) is not conceptually different from `ls`'s output `.  ..  td`. It's also the output of a command, just another one: your shell.

Comment: Great answer. Could there be an emulator ? or maybe a client that have this feature ??

Comment: No. What kind of "emulator" or "client" do you think of? Shells and similar tools, if run interactively, are designed to run in terminals. You might get varying fonts on web pages, word documents etc., but those are on the other hand not suitable platforms for running shells and other Unix commands.

Comment: I was thinking of an app that has two fields, which can have separate font settings. The upper field is a line input that will hold the prompt line. The lower field is a multi - line that will show the results of the command fired in the upper field... Could be an idea for a new app? Most probably it's available somewhere...